# Edittext only allow letters (programmatically)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keyboard

I'm trying to get an editTextview that only allows letters (lower- and uppercase).

It works with this code:

```
 edittv.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
```

The problem is that I get a numerical keyboard like this:

[image: keyboard example]

To go back to a normal keyboard I found this code:

```
edittv.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"));
edittv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

It works for getting the keyboard back but then all characters are allowed again, so it undo's the previous code.

So, how can I only allow letters with an alphabetical keyboard programatically.

Comment: If I switch them then only the letters are allowed again, which is good, but I get a numerical keyboard again.

Comment: @DaanSeuntjens I updated my answer please check..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code below:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))&&!Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(i))) {
            return "";
        }
    }
    return null;
}
};
edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you are using `DigitsKeyListener` extends `NumberKeyListener` which only allows numbers thats why you were getting that error.

Here is my solution for your requirements use this lines in your XML.

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "/>
```

**Note :- Space is given at the end of digits for let user input space also**

For Programmatically :-

```
    edittv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    edittv.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
            new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                           int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                    if (src.equals("")) {
                        return src;
                    }
                    if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                        return src;
                    }
                    return "";
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: The textview is created dynamically using code so using xml isn't an option.

Comment: It seems correct but I will check @bhumilvyas answer because he was first with an answer using setFilter. I upvoted you instead because it is aswell a wright answer, hope you understand.