# Allow AndroidX EditTextPreference to only accept letters

Tags: android, android-edittext, androidx, edittextpreference

I have an EditTextPreference set up with a filter to limit it's size, like so:

```
pref.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
            }
        });
```

I want to also limit it to only accept letters (not just a-zA-Z, since the app accepts more than one language). How can I go about doing this?

I have tried many filters before, including all of those suggested in these questions and similar:

[Making an EditText field accept only letters and white spaces in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057279/making-an-edittext-field-accept-only-letters-and-white-spaces-in-android)

[Edittext only allow letters (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002816/edittext-only-allow-letters-programmatically)

With filters like those, whenever a number is inputted and then a letter, I get issues like:
- The whole text disappears
- The whole text gets duplicated
- The last few characters get duplicated

I also tried changing the XML by adding and `android:digits`, but no matter what it doesn't restrict the input at all.
Every `inputType` I've tried so far does not restrict the keyboard to only letters.

**EDIT:** I figured it out, answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a TextWatcher to the EditText, and replaced the text with a regex, like this:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        String replaced = s.toString().replaceAll("[^[:alpha:] ]", "");
                        editText.setText(replaced);
                        editText.setSelection(replaced.length());
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
```

This lets letters be added in, but when anything else is typed, it doesn't show up and isn't saved anywhere. The `setSelection()` method is there to put the cursor at the end of the string, otherwise it resets to the beginning.

Comment: Your filter option is correct, but you're adding a ChangeListener to an EditText object. Why don't you just use your EditTextPref with the OnBindTextListener from the question?